# C++11 - Passing vector from function as iterator

Tags: c++11, vector, stl

This is probably a simple problem, however, it is causing me a lot of confusion.

I have a class member that returns a populated vector:

```
vector<double> returnVector()
{
    return theVector;
}
```

I also have a function that is called `toArray()` that accepts an Iterator so that I can alternate between the type of the values that I pass in. For example:

```
template<typename T, typename Inverse>
T* toArray(Inverse begin, Inverse end)
{
    size_t size = distance(begin, end);
    auto pos = 0;

    T* tmp = new T[size];

    for(auto i = begin; i != end; i++)
    {
        tmp[pos] = *i;
        pos++;
    }
    return tmp;

}
```

Inside my main I thought it would be possible to do the following;

```
MyClass class; 

auto* var = Functs::toArray<double>(
                std::begin(class.returnVector()),
                std::end(class.returnVector())
            );
```

This however, does not work and I seem to be getting some malloc error. However, I am able to do the following:

```
MyClass class;

vector<double> vals = class.returnVector(); 
auto* var = Functs::toArray<double>(
    std::begin(vals),
    std::end(vals)
);
```

Could anyone explain to why this is happening? I was under the assumption that because the function `returnVector` returns the actual vector, it is therefore possible to be able to access from `begin` to `end`?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but remember that your `returnVector` function returns a *copy* of the vector. You might want to return a reference (or possibly a `const` reference).

Comment: As for your problems, you should first run your program in a debugger to pinpoint the errors, as they seem to be runtime errors. Then you have to tell us about the errors in more detail, like providing more code to what you actually do, and possibly the callstack of a potential crash.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I seem to get `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Abort trap: 6` I'll attempt to debug.. When I tried to print out the `std::distance(begin, end);` the number is way more than it should be.

Comment: Please show the complete code of `toArray` as that is very important to crashes or exceptions in that function. Also, what is the size of that vector?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Just updated my post with the code. I don't see how it could crash the program since on a normal vector, it works? Thanks for your replies btw

Comment: you get a `begin` iterator for one array, and an `end` iterator for a totally different array! They just happen to have the same content.

Comment: @Dave And that is the correct answer. So you should probably post it as such. :)

Comment: (incidentally, wouldn't be an issue if you return by reference, if that's an option)

Comment: @Dave Thank you. So should I therefore be returning the vector inside `returnVector` as a reference?

Comment: The second code sample is valid, so you probably stick with it

Comment: OK, posted an answer. It has suggestions.

Comment: Updated answer with a better suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
Functs::toArray<double>(
    std::begin(class.returnVector()),
    std::end(class.returnVector())
);
```

your `returnVector` method returns by value, so you get a copy. That means the two calls produce two *different* vectors. This is why you are getting a much larger range than you expect, and why you end up accessing invalid memory.

If you are able to, change `returnVector` to return a reference instead. But if that isn't an option, you'll just have to remember to always store a local reference to it, as you do in your other example.

Another option would be to define a convenience overload:

```
template<typename T>
T* toArray(std::vector<T>& vec) {
    return toArray( std::begin( vec ), std::end( vec ) );
}
```

which you can call like this:

```
auto* var = Functs::toArray( class.returnVector() );
```

Personally I would go with that option.

Comment: hmm, actually you might need to make 2 overloads: `T* toArray(const T& vec)` and `T* toArray(T&& vec)` (the latter needs C++11). But I don't know for sure; it depends on the return type of `returnVector` in ways which I can't remember off the top of my head. YMMV and all that.

Comment: The OP is basically remaking `std::vector::data`

Comment: @Rapptz yes, it seems they are. But I'm going to give the benefit of the doubt and assume that this is a simplified example of what they actually want to do with the iterators.

Comment: @Dave Thank you for this, really found it helpful :) Decided to go with returning a reference to the vector.

Answer (score 2):

Your code

```
size_t size = distance(begin, end);
```

has undefined behavior if `end` is not (always) reachable from `begin` **[iterator.requirements.general]**.
This is the case of the first example that uses `toArray`. The second example is valid.

It’s better if you change `returnVector` to

```
vector<double> const& returnVector() const;
```

and rather than `toArray` use

```
vector<double>::data();
```

In general, it’s best if you avoid returning raw pointers to allocated data.